# Flask redirect login

Tags: javascript, python, css, flask, wtforms

I am new to flask and I learn flask from twt. I try to do a very simple login page with no CSS. I want every time when a user logs can't go again to the login page or any different web page of my site. Is there any solution?
Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask,redirect,url_for,render_template,request,session,flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin,LoginManager,login_user,login_required,logout_user,current_user
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired,Length
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
import requests
app =  Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users1.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abc'
class users(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200),unique=False,nullable=False)

db.create_all()
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Username',validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=2,max=30,message='Name must be from 2 to 30')])
    password = PasswordField("Password",validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=1,max=30,message='Password must be from 1 to 30')])

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Username',validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=2,max=30,message='Name must be from 2 to 30')])
    password = PasswordField("Password",validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=1,max=30,message='Password must be from 1 to 30')])
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    return users.query.get(user_id)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    form = RegisterForm()
    try:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = users(name=form.name.data,password=generate_password_hash(form.password.data,method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/login')
    except:
        return 'Name does exist'
    return render_template("register.html",form=form)

@app.route('/login',methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    form1 = LoginForm()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(request.referrer)
    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        user1 = users.query.filter_by(name=form1.name.data).first()
        if user1:
            if check_password_hash(user1.password,form1.password.data):
                login_user(user1)
                return redirect('/home')
            else:
                return 'Password is incorrect'
        else:
            return 'Name does not exist'
    return render_template("login.html",form=form1)

@app.route("/home")
@login_required
def home1():
    return 'asd'

@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return 'You logged out'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And this is the code of register.html and login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action='' method='post'>
            {{form.csrf_token}}
            {{form.name.label}}
            {{form.name}}
            {%for i in form.name.errors%}
                <p style='color:red;'>{{i}}</p>
            {%endfor%}
            {{form.password.label}}
            {{form.password}}
            {%for b in form.name.errors%}
                <p style="color:red;">{{b}}</p>
            {%endfor%}
            <button>Register</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using flask-sessions. At the time when you are logging in a user and verifying its password and email, create session variables. Example:

```
session['loggedIn']= True
```

And, when the user logs out, delete these session variables:

```
session.pop('loggedIn',None)
```

Now, if you want to restrict a user from visiting a particular route, use the if condition to check if he is loggedIn:

```
@main.route('/myLink')
def myLink():
    if session['loggedIn'] is True:
        return render_template('thisPage.html')
    else:
        return("You are not logged in")
```